# getting instance of iframe (node) from within iframe (same domain)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a situation where I need to know which instance of an iframe the code is running from. The "parent" document is itself generated by code and I have no access to the mechanism that generates it (and it regenerates regularly). My document is loaded *more than once* in multiple iframes on the page, at various locations (the iframes are not siblings). I want each instance of the script to be able to access the iframe NODE that loaded that instance of the script.

Here's the rough idea. For each "a.html"'s running code, I want it to know the iframe ELEMENT that it is running in.

[image]

in this example there will be three instances of the same code running from "a.html". I want to be able to look to the parent document (which I can - this is not a cross-domain problem) and find out the ID or some other dynamically assigned property of the iframe - so I need the ELEMENT reference of the iframe itself.

Asking for the "parent" element of an iframe doesn't inform the parent javascript instance of which element is executing that request AFAIK. Is there?

I can't just iterate all iframes and look for my pages known source "a.html" because there will be multiple instances of the same path, as well as other iframes that have nothing to do with me - which IFRAME is the current execution context?

Things I can't do:

1. Modify the parent page
2. Modify the iframe URLs, including the name or using search parameters
3. Specify the ids or dataset values on the iframes.

Things I can do:

1. Modify the contents of the child iframes

The only way I have at the moment is for "a.html" to generate a (hopefully) unique value and store it on the document, then ask the parent context to iterate all iframes and seek that value within the child contexts, then when it matches there would be the node that is calling the request.

Thoughts?

Comment: The nature as what a node is, is very vague. Is it an element? text? How does it all of the sudden get generated? By a function? Event? What exactly is this value you are looking for? An array? Object? Number? String?

Comment: the `node` is the iframe `element` that loaded the instance of `a.html`. An automated external process generates the file which references `a.html` based on an external event. When my script which runs inside `a.html` knows what the iframe that loaded that instance of `a.html` is, it will read an attribute from that `iframe element` (either its `id` or a value from its dataset collection), then use that value inside the script running inside `a.html` to do stuff with. `a.html` MIGHT be embedded on the same page multiple times, each `iframe` will have a different id, and run on each instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've learned a few things.

1. There doesn't appear to be a way in javascript to "know" which iframe triggered an event. A `console.trace()` won't tell you the dom context that the script executed in, even if some of it executed in one document and another function executed in the parent document.
2. As usual I was overthinking it by trying to see what node the script executed within, or where an event came from, rather than identifying what I know already - the window name property (which is luckily unique in my situation), and dom nodes. Iterate the parents iframes until it matches the one I need.

Within child iframe (a.html):

```js
const n = window.name; // 'window' is the iframe document a.html
window.parent.getIframe = function (name) {
    // in the context of the function, 'this' is the parent 'window' element.
    const iframes = this.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (let i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
        if (iframes[i].name == name) {
            return iframes[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
const frame = window.parent.getIframe(n);
let prop = frame.dataset.someValue ... etc
```